# show image in its original resolution in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, imshow

I have a very high resolution(3311, 4681, 3) image, which I want to show in my jupyter notebook using opencv but as other answers stated its not possible to use `cv2.imshow` in the jupyter notebook, so i used `plt.imshow` to do the same but the problem is I have to define the fig_size parameter if I want to display my image larger. How can I read the image in its original resolution in jupyter notebook or is it possible to open the image in another window?

This is what I have tried :

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

img = cv2.imread(r"0261b27431-07_D_01.jpg")
plt.figure(figsize= (20,20))
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image]

So basically I want my image to show in its original resolution in jupyter notebook or in another window.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can `imshow` the image in its original resolution by calculating the corresponding figure size, which depends on the dpi (dots per inch) value of matplotlib. The default value is 100 dpi and is stored in `matplotlib.rcParams['figure.dpi']`.

So `imshow`ing the image like this

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib 
%matplotlib inline

# Acquire default dots per inch value of matplotlib
dpi = matplotlib.rcParams['figure.dpi']

img = cv2.imread(r'0261b27431-07_D_01.jpg')

# Determine the figures size in inches to fit your image
height, width, depth = img.shape
figsize = width / float(dpi), height / float(dpi)

plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

prints it in its large resolution, but with the drawback, that the axis labels are tiny compared to the large image. You can workaround this by setting other `rcParams` to larger values, e.g.

```
# Do the same also for the 'y' axis
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 50
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.major.size'] = 15
matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.major.width'] = 5
...
```

---

Your second suggestion to open the image in another window would work like this, that you change the matplotlib backend using Ipython magic commands by replacing `%matplotlib inline` in the above example with, e.g.

```
%matplotlib qt         # opens the image in an interactive window with original resolution
```

or

```
%matplotlib notebook    # opens the image in an interactive window 'inline'
```

See [here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#what-is-a-backend) for more backend possibilites. Note that the calculation of the original figure size has to be done before also.

Comment: Second one, what should I use for that plt.show or cv2.imshow?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar also `plt.show()`. You just replace the `%matplotlib inline` magic with one of the listed ones in my answer. The rest of the example remains the same.

Comment: the window that its opening is still small, I have to zoom into it to get a larger view of the picture

Comment: did you also execute the determination of the figure size and `plt.figure(figsize=figsize)` before as stated in the upper half of my answer?

Answer (score -1):

In order to show image in full original resolution,
You can also use `PIL`

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(r'0261b27431-07_D_01.jpg')
img
```